# what is the best XML database? is really have better performance than relational db?

Tags: xml, database

I worked with Oracle and this db have good options but is not xml base db, i want to know what db have better performance in insert and get xpath query?

I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database that introduce some databases like baseX, eXist, sedna, MarkLogic Server, MonetDB, 28msec platform, ..

I think BaseX and eXist (that written with java) have not good performance than the other databases that written with c++, is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's deal with the last point first: if you imagine that software written in Java is necessarily slower than software written in C++, then you are living in the dark ages.

As for the overall question, there aren't any reliable independent benchmarks, and even if they were, their results would almost certainly be untypical of your workload.

If performance really is your number one reason for choosing one product over another, then you will have to make your own measurements. But usually nowadays, unless it's a really high-stress workload, other factors such as usability have much more impact on project success or failure.

Comment: As you like, (last point first :D) when java run on machine that run over OS and c++ run over OS, i think java & .net is lower performance because its worked over something like machine, its so similar to script language merge with a language with compiler.. and the other i really want to know about your or other persons working experience with XML DBs that be stable enough for running something like SCM(Supply Chain Management), i start SCM project for railway and i want to know, is XMLDBs grow ups enough? and thanks for answer.

Comment: Never speculate about performance. Always make measurements, and base your arguments on controlled observation. Yes, there are lots of projects using XML databases for very critical and high-performance applications. Success in such projects depends on having the right skills in your team much more than on the technology itself.